# Expected SELECT statement

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
WITH 1_hour_trips as (
    SELECT *
    from bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips
    where tripduration = 60
)
```

Comment: this code shows the following error; Syntax error: Expected "(" or "," or keyword SELECT but got end of script at [5:2]

Answer (score 1):

[`WITH`](https://modern-sql.com/feature/with) creates a temporary view, and it then expects you to use a select to actually get the result you want. Something like this:

```
WITH 1_hour_trips as (
    SELECT * from bigquery-public-data.new_york.citibike_trips
    where tripduration = 60
)
SELECT * from 1_hour_trips;
```